# How to get data from SQLite in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, sql, sqlite, flutter

I am new with flutter and SQLite so I am trying to get data from database which I created DB Browser for SQLite.

I am getting this on console:
"/flutter ( 9624): Instance of 'Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>'"

I don't know it's a error or warning but I can't see data on console.

Here is the codes on my main.dart class and database_helper class.

```
Future<Database> _getDatabase() async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await _initializeDatabase();
      return _database;
    } else {
      return _database;
    }
  }

  Future<Database> _initializeDatabase() async {
    var lock = Lock();
    Database _db;

    if (_db == null) {
      await lock.synchronized(() async {
        if (_db == null) {
          var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
          var path = join(databasesPath, "appDB.db");
          var file = new File(path);

          // check if file exists
          if (!await file.exists()) {
            // Copy from asset
            ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "myNotes.db"));
            List<int> bytes =
                data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
            await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
          }
          // open the database
          _db = await openDatabase(path);
        }
      });
    }

    return _db;
  }

  showCategories() async {
    var db = await _getDatabase();
    var categoryList = db.query("kategori");
    print(categoryList);
  }
```

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
    databaseHelper.showCategories();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Text(""),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `await` here: var categoryList = db.query("kategori");

Answer (score 0):

The error might be caused due to a return type inconsistency. Do check out this article on flutter databases

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flutter/flutter_database_concepts.htm